# When was hardware acceleration support added to KDE?

Tags: kde, desktop-environment

I'm curious about KDE desktop history and I want to know when was hardware acceleration support added to KDE?I know that Microsoft introduced the same in windows vista but I haven't any clue about KDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re referring to full-desktop visual effects, commonly implemented by compositing windows using OpenGL, those were added to KDE [in version 4.0](https://kde.org/announcements/4.0/) in July 2008.